# Select count of unique elements in certain groups

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets assume I have a table `history` which has two columns `user_id` and `room_id`. I want to select count of unique **users** in each **room**. The output should look like that:

| unique_count | room_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 11 |
| 15 | 12 |
| 251 | 14 |

for example, here is **251** unique **users** in the **room 14**.

I use this query to achieve my goal:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT h.user_id) AS unique_count, h.room_id
FROM history AS h
GROUP BY h.room_id
```

of course it selects correct output, but it is kind of slow and is there any other options to make the query faster?

Comment: Count distinct queries are hard to optimize.  One workaround would be to maintain your table such that you don't need to invoke distinct.

Comment: This is the straight-forward query. Provide an index: `CREATE INDEX idx ON history (room_id, user_id)`. That is about all you can do here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some ideas.

- Do you have an index on `(room_id, user_id)`?
- Some (parallel) databases are more efficient by doing the `distinct` and then the `count`:

```
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS unique_count, h.room_id
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT h.user_id, h.room_id
          FROM history h
         ) h
    GROUP BY h.room_id;
```

- A correlated subquery (with the above index) *might* help:

```
    select room_id,
           (select count(distinct h.user_id)
            from history h
            where h.room_id = r.room_id
           )
    from rooms r;
```

I'm not sure if any of these will improve performance on your data, but they are some ideas you can try.